# android Low memory:no more background process ?? Need help

Tags: android, memory-management, android-layout

I am facing the problem of low memory. `Low memory:no more background process` And here is the scenario.

I am using a list which gets its data from a string array, it has a custom background, Clicking on item, the list gets another string array to display as second or third level. Information for three levels written in database.

After third level, there are two more levels for which data is going to be fetched from web services,

And that causes the low memory error.

<strike>How can I get rid of the solution?</strike>

***Edit :*** After having some digging I found that the GC is trying to (kill or) restart in case of its already crashed `com.android.inputmethod.latin/.latinIME`service. One notable point is that the application is translated in french and italian, but this screen does not have any text for translation, does this information helps??

**Edit 2:** After a detailed study of traceview I found that all the text views have custom fonts applied in it. (There is a call of TypeFace.createFromAsset()) that IMO causes the crashes.

And the problem lies in the fact that I have to keep the fonts.... 
<strike>can It be possible to avoid crash and have the fonts??</strike> (Because i think the answer is no: But still waiting for some opinions)

**Edit 3** : After removing the custom fonts the performance of application is much better. Hence I can suspect the font is the only culprit here. And that's why I am editing question. The font I use is helvetica.

Can using external fonts cause application to crash or running out of memory? If yes can you describe the cause in more detail??

Thanks

Comment: How big are these "string arrays"? I suggest using DDMS to monitor the state of your heap as you step through the levels...

Comment: not more than 100 to 400 on third level. The second level has avg of 500 each, can applying custom fonts cause low memory error???

Comment: Well temporarily take out the custom fonts and see if it helps. If it does then you know that that's your problem. You should provide more information btw... *what* actually crashes, *what* fonts are you using, etc etc etc.

Comment: Not sure if it will help but try defining setting the the freezes text variable like this: "android:freezesText="true" for the components that will be related with your list and its items.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using code similar to:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
"fonts/Helvetica.ttf");
```

try making "font" a global variable so it only gets loaded once. Otherwise it can be loaded repeatedly, quickly consuming memory. [See this message](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/msg/32a5b70a05ca982d) for a little more detail

Comment: i agree with this answer, as I have run into the same memory issue using custom font files.  load the font as few times as possible and your app will be fine

Comment: Thanks Cameron, I didn't thought about it. Actually we accidentally un-commented the line and that cause the font to be generated every time a text view is being created. Thanks A LOT.

Comment: @MobileDev123: It is always the little things that cause the biggest problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, question is a bit unclear to have answered:

1. After each level - do you switch/start to another Activity? If so you shouldn't keep anywhere references to old activity. Otherwise it could trigger OOM problems
2. I suppose you're fetching data using some kind of `Cursor` alike object. `Cursor`'s are very memory-consuming objects, so you'd better not only just close `Cursor`'s, but you should also call `Cursor.deactivate()`

Comment: 1. No its the same activity, I just change in list adapter. 2. I use array adapter here not cursor adapter.

Comment: Can you tell me what additional information should i provide to make the question clear??